# Large Scale App: Multiple Vue apps or one Vue app with multiple components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am beginning a project where I am tasked with combining 7 codebases into 1 codebase. Each of these codebases are very different and handle different functions (Registration, Surveys, Email Blaster, etc). I would like to use Vue for the frontend of each of these (Laravel on the backend).

My initial structure for this project involves using one app.js file with one Vue instance and separating each of the codebases into components. Vue-Router will determine which one of the components gets loaded.

```
//example of the layout thusfar
let routes = [
    { path: '/registration', component: require('./components/admin/Registration.vue').default },
    { path: '/surveys', component: require('./components/admin/Surveys.vue').default }
]
```

Is this the best way to layout my project? If not, is there a better way to structure a project like this?

Comment: Depends, do they all belong in the same application or in different applications?

Comment: @StevenB. They are different codebases with different functionalities. They will all use the same api calls though. I'd rather combine everything into one Vue instance, but I don't know if this is correct or recommended.

Comment: @TrapMoney Did you ever decide on a path with this? I'm currently doing (somewhat) the same - trying to share multiple Vue components (standalone Vue instances) across several apps.